# Clean way of avoiding NullPointerException in equals checks

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, equals, coding-style

I have an address object that I want to create an equals method for. I could have made this quite simple by doing something like the following (shortened a bit):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
    if (this == obj)
        return true;

    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    Address other = (Address) obj;

    return this.getStreet().equals(other.getStreet())
        && this.getStreetNumber().equals(other.getStreetNumber())
        && this.getStreetLetter().equals(other.getStreetLetter())
        && this.getTown().equals(other.getTown());
}
```

Problem is, some of these might be null. I will in other words get a `NullPointerException` if there is no street letter in this address.

How can I write this in a clean way while taking null values into account?

Comment: using the *@NotNull* annotation everywhere surely helps.  So does using empty strings and empty arrays, instead of null string and null arrays to represent something that is "empty".  An empty string is a string that contains no character.  An empty array is an array made of zero element.  "null" and NPEs are exceedingly rare in our codebase, where the *@NotNull* annotation is used in every single class we have :)

Comment: in addition to that, the concept of "equality" over mutable object doesn't make much sense.  Make your objects immutable.  Forbid null.  Everything will be smoother.

Comment: Of course, and I would if I could! Problem is that in this case these things *can* be non-existent. For example, not all addresses have a letter, so it should be null. On the matter of immutability, I totally agree, but unfortunately it's not my choice. If it was up to me, it would be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a helper method like

```
public static boolean isEqual(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return o1 == o2 || (o1 != null && o1.equals(o2));
}
```

Comment: Nice and concise! Wouldn't it be `areEqual` though?

Comment: @Svish Not necessarily. _Is_ Object o1 _equal_ to Object o2?

Comment: The method is available in java.util.Objects since 1.7. You can use it directly. Objects.equals(o1, o2).

Answer (score 11):

[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides [Objects.equal(Object, Object)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) which checks for equality while taking into consideration that either of the parameters might be null:

```
...
return Objects.equal(this.getStreet(), other.getStreet())
    && Objects.equal(this.getStreetNumber(), other.getStreetNumber())
    && Objects.equal(this.getStreetLetter(), other.getStreetLetter())
    && Objects.equal(this.getTown(), other.getTown());
```

It's also worth pointing out that Objects has other helper methods for implementing  [hashCode()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object...%29) and [toString()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#toStringHelper%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 9):

You could do the following:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }

    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Address other = (Address) obj;

    return equals(this.getStreet(),other.getStreet())
        && equals(this.getStreetNumber(), other.getStreetNumber())
        && equals(this.getStreetLetter(), other.getStreetLetter())
        && equals(this.getTown(), other.getTown());
}

private boolean equals(Object control, Object test) {
    if(null == control) {
        return null == test;
    }
    return control.equals(test);
}
```

Java 7 introduced built-in support for this use case with the java.util.Objects class see:

- [java.utils.Objects.equals(Object, Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)
- [java.utils.Objects.deepEquals(Object, Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: @Svish  It will look cleaner  + it would be optimum too.

Comment: @Jigar, Personally I think it looks cleaner as it is. But why would it be optimum? No matter have you look at it, you have 3 checks that potentially have to be done. And if any of them go through, you'd stop execution. Is there some compiler optimizations I don't know about or something?

Comment: @Swish Well if you use Collections and if you look for a object and if it invokes equal method for each object there would be atleast 3 * n  + rest in `equal` method check performed , where if you use else if , then in worst case it would happen.

Comment: I think this is probably what I would do. Maybe make that method a static method in a utility class or something, but yeah... lot cleaner than doing all those null checks mixed in.

Comment: @Blaise: -1 to your question for not enclosing the body of if statements in parenthesis. I mean, c'mon, this 2011 not the 1960's. It is a terrible practice to leave the parenthesis out, a practice we have known for decades to increase the incidence of defects.

Comment: @Jigar: if I could -neg rep your comment, I would. Why is it optimum? Both forms get compiled to the exact same bytecode. Those two sets of if (and if-else) statements are syntactically equivalent (hint, you need to learn how compilers work). Also, bringing a hypothetical collections-based scenario does not validate your argument since it is not applicable to the specific code snippet under consideration - that's poor engineering thinking.

Comment: @luis: +1. Even if it was non-performant (it's not), that wouldn't matter unless a it was causing a measurable delay to the total performance of the application. Bottom line: making performance claims without measurements is a big mistake.

Comment: @luis.espinal - I agree (it is now fixed).  Honestly my answer was focused on the question about the null check and I just copied and pasted from the OP and modified the piece specific to the question.

Comment: About the missing `{ }`, I sometimes leave them out and sometimes don't. Depends if they make things clearer or not. In general I tend to leave them out if it's a simple `return` or `throw` statement. If it's something else I tend to add them.

Answer (score 4):

I have a helper class Checker w/ a static method:

```
 public static boolean isEquals(final Object o1, final Object o2) {
        return o1 == null ? o2 == null : o1.equals(o2);
 }
```

so, in the equals method,

```
 return Checker.isEquals(this.getStreet(), other.getStreet())
        && Checker.isEquals(this.getStreetNumber(), other.getStreetNumber())
        && Checker.isEquals(this.getStreetLetter(), other.getStreetLetter())
        && Checker.isEquals(this.getTown(), other.getTown());
```

Comment: I call my "Checker" class "public class NullSafe" instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is no really clean way to do that; the best option is probably to have your IDE generate the code for you. Eclipse can do it via the Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals() context menu.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Objects.equal](http://guava-ibraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html) from Googles guava or the [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) from apache commons

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.Objects.equals(a, b)` if you want an **official** way (built-in).

*(There is already a mention to it in one of the answers, but more as a sidenote)*

Change:

```
this.getStreet().equals(other.getStreet())
```

To:

```
Objects.equals(this.getStreet(), other.getStreet())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider defining some of the equals methods as static class methods, like say for the Street objects. This way you don't ever attempt to call the .equals() method on a null.

A sample function might look like:

```
public static boolean equals(Object one, Object two)
```

Also, it's good practice to put checks like

```
if (obj == null)
   return false;
```

at the very beginning of a function.

Comment: Yeah, must say I miss the static `Equals` method you have on objects in C#. Would be handy in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) provides the [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/index.html) helper class for equality comparissons. There is also one for hash codes.

```
return new EqualsBuilder()
.append(this.getStreet(), other.getStreet())
.append(this.getStreetNumber(), other.getStreetNumber()
.append(this.getStreetLetter(), other.getStreetLetter())
.append(this.getTown(), other.getTown())).isEquals();
```